# Is there an easy way of seeing PHP info?

Tags: php

Each time I want to see the `phpinfo();` I have to:

- Create a info.php file;
- Write `phpinfo();` in it.
- Go to the browser and type my "thisproject.dev/info.php"

I'm on Ubuntu.

Isn't there a more practical way to see phpinfo in the browser?

Comment: As @Jaitsu and Brian Gordon wrote, you can access PHP via command line, but what they didn't mention is that sometimes PHP in command line is different from one in Apache, i.e., they work in different modes and might even have different config files.

Comment: @binaryLV good point, one i overlooked when I answered

Answer (score 333, accepted):

From your command line you can run..

```
php -i
```

I know it's not the browser window, but you can't see the `phpinfo();` contents without making the function call.

Another approach would be to have a PHP script in the root of your web server directory that calls `phpinfo();`, that way you have access to it at all times via `http://localhost/info.php` or something similar. However, this is NOT suitable for a production environment unless you ensure that you secure it.

EDIT: As mentioned by binaryLV, its quite common to have two versions of a php.ini per installation. One for the command line interface (CLI) and the other for the web server interface. If you want to see phpinfo output for your web server make sure you specify the ini file path, for example...

```
php -c /etc/php/apache2/php.ini -i
```

Comment: Don't forget to *secure* it, as output of `phpinfo()` should not be publicly accessible.

Comment: There is also a good reason for [NOT LINKING](http://askubuntu.com/questions/321019/php-ini-cli-symbolic-link) the 2 `php.ini` especially if you are working on a public server.

Comment: You should really just use the -c flag and pass in the path for the proper .ini file instead of doing something like symlinking or whatnot.

Comment: @ChrisRasys why would you want to have to specify it every time you run CLI scripts?

Comment: @JamesHalsall If you need to emulate the PHP settings that your web server is using, that's the proper way to do it. Otherwise you're either erroneously using the CLI settings, or you're removing the separation between CLI settings and web server settings. That separation does exist for a reason.

Comment: Whilst that might be useful for some, I usually use the same ini for both. I've only seen debian distributions use the separate ini for apache and CLI

Comment: This can be misleading as the PHP binary is not the same as the PHP module that is loaded by apache check this post: https://superuser.com/questions/969861/phpinfo-and-php-v-shows-different-version-of-php

Comment: I hope my edit gets accepted, but anyway: 6 upvotes for @binaryLV is way too little, this should be in bold in the answer: **phpinfo should not be publicly accessible** I wonder how many breaches have been made possible over the years by the "best approach" in this answer.

Comment: To add to that: Our logs show that servers are **actively scanned** for the mentioned endpoint "/info.php". Either update your answer or take it down JamesHalsall, I can't believe this has been up for 7 years.

Comment: @Douwe if you read my answer, it says `http://localhost/info.php` - I did not say to expose it in production or publicly

Comment: @JamesHalsall You start that sentence with "the best approach would be to have a phpinfo script in the root of your web server directory". So any novice that thinks "oh, but mine is on a different domain, I'll use that because it's "something simular" would not be warned. Even bigger issue: A lot of IDE's auto-add files to git. Again, this is actively being exploited, cross referencing phpinfo()'s output with known vulnerabilities is very, very easy. OP's approach of removing after use is actually a far better "best approach" than this.

Comment: Today it is quite common to have php compiled with ``--with-config-file-scan-dir=/etc/php/XXX/XXX/conf.d`` (Debian/ Ubuntu ) 
If that is the case you need to run ``export PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR=/etc/php/XXX/XXX/conf.d`` and than ``php -c XXX -i`` to get the exact same result than phpinfo(); in your browser. You can check which php ini files are loaded with ``php -c /etc/php/XXX/XXX/php.ini --ini``

Answer (score 28):

If you have php installed on your local machine try:

```
$ php -a
Interactive shell

php > phpinfo();
```

Comment: Does this get the `php.ini` of the cli version or the one in apache? In my case I use 2 `php.ini` for cli and apache.

Comment: I tried this and it gets the `php.ini` from the CLI version. If you keep 2 versions of `php.ini` this might not be applicable.

Answer (score 27):

From the CLI the best way is to use `grep` like:

```
php -i | grep libxml
```

Comment: This is a nice way to search in the php ini.

Answer (score 17):

From the CLI:

```
php -r 'phpinfo();'
```

Comment: My webhost (debian 7):  php -r 'phpinfo();'
Error in argument 1, char 2: option not found r
php -v
PHP 4.4.9 (cgi-fcgi) (built: Feb 28 2017 11:31:58)

Comment: works fine in php 5 and above

Answer (score 3):

Use the command line.

`touch /var/www/project1/html/phpinfo.php && echo '<?php phpinfo(); ?>' >> /var/www/project1/html/phpinfo.php && firefox --url localhost/project1/phpinfo.php`

Something like that? Idk!

Answer (score 2):

You can use this command to print phpinfo to file .txt:

> touch phpinfo.txt && php -i >> phpinfo.txt && sudo gedit phpinfo.txt

Explain about that code:

1. Create new file:

> touch phpinfo.txt

2. Print phpinfo() to file .txt:

> php -i >> phpinfo.txt

3. Open file:

> sudo gedit phpinfo.txt

Hope it's help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WAMP then type the following in the browser
http://localhost/?phpinfo=-1,
you will get the phpinfo page.

[phpinfo() from localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlv34.png)

You can also click the localhost icon in the wamp menu from the systray and then find the phpinfo page.
[WAMP localhost from WAMP Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkKrx.png)